# Is there a discrete random variable function with which I can specify the probability of returning a value?

Tags: random

I am trying to create a function `s[n_]` which returns a subset of $\{ 1,2,3 \dots n\}$ wherein each integer $j$ appears with probability $1/j$; ie. there is a $1/4$ chance that $4$ belongs to `s[i]` for $i \geq 4$.

The only way I can think of doing this is actually assembling a list of lists where sets containing, say, $4$, appear $1/4$  of the time. But certainly there is a built-in function for discrete random variables with specified probabilities? I would guess so, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: You picked the better answer.  So sometimes it's better to wait a day (or more) rather than pick the first answer given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation that is not only more concise, but also 10x faster:

```
s[n_]:=Select[
 Range[n],
 RandomReal[] < 1/# &]
```

Comment: +1 Yes, much better!

Answer (score 3):

I assume from what you describe the number 1 is always returned (as its probability of being selected is 1).

```
SeedRandom[12345]
s[n_] := Module[{list}, 
  list = (RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/#], 1][[1]] & /@ Range[n]) Range[n];
  Select[list, # != 0 &]]

s[5]
(* {1, 4} *)
s[20]
(* {1} *)
s[4]
(* {1,3,4} *)
```